# Create Custom Dialog Box With Multiple In Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view, ionic-native

I want to create custom dialog box having multiple option to filter the data and i knew how to open the custom dialog by using modal in ionic.
i had played around with ionic docs but didn't find any about it

Here are screen that i want to achieve

[image]
[image]

[image]

Please give some idea to achieve the same.